# How to insert a row from one database to the same table in other databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to insert one specific row from one Table to other tables with same name but in different databases, something like the following:

```
 Table Makers from database A

 id  | name | type | comments
 01    OSLO    A      None

 Table Makers from database B is empty but same structure as A
 id  | name | type | comments

 Table Makers from database C is empty but same structure as A and B
 id  | name | type | comments
```

I have a query that does the job but I need to change the name of the database manually, that is.

```
Use database_B
Go
Insert into Makers
       ([id], [name], [type], [comments])
select [id], [name], [type], [comments] from database_A
where id = '01'

Use database_C
Go
Insert into Makers
       ([id], [name], [type], [comments])
select [id], [name], [type], [comments] from database_A
where id = '01'
```

Is there an alternative to do this same process without repeating the same insertion code?

Any suggestion to improve this question to make it more valuable is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have both databases in the same server you can use the syntax `[database].[schema].[table]` to refer to tables in other databases. That saves you the `use database_X` sentence but you will still need a different insert for each destination table. Example:

```
Insert into [database_C].[dbo].Makers ([id], [name], [type], [comments])
select [id], [name], [type], [comments] 
from [database_A].[dbo].Makers
where id = '01'

Insert into [database_B].[dbo].Makers ([id], [name], [type], [comments])
select [id], [name], [type], [comments] 
from [database_A].[dbo].Makers
where id = '01'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have one table that's a master and the rest are just copies, consider synonyms. If all tables can accept edits that you want propagated, consider merge replication. If real time alignment isn't necessary and a batch process will suffice, consider an SSIS package with a multi-cast transformation.